# Pygame.movie missing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspbian, movie

I am currently working with a RPi 3B (latest Raspbian Jessie) on a little project which involves playing a short .mp4 file. As Pygame seemed to support playing .mpg files, so I converted my video into that format.

When I tried to import the movie module however, I get the common python import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "film_app.py", line 3, in <module>
       import pygame.movie
ImportError: No module named movie
```

After some research, I figured others had the same issue as described [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/238/no-module-named-pygamemovie). I did not really understand if there is a solution to it, or what alternatives I have on a RPi.

Pygame, python and Raspbian are up to date.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com),
The policy is to have only one question per 'page'.You might would like to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`movie` is not a sub package of `pygame`

Use it like this:

```
movie = pygame.movie.Movie("file.mpg")
```

Note however:

The movie api is deprecated and your pygame will most likely not contain any code for this api.

The code will just throw a NotImplementedError exception.

Sadly you cant use pygame for movies like this anymore.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/238/no-module-named-pygamemovie#comment-19463276) Lenard Lindstrom explains this:

> "Though not properly documented, the pygame.movie module has been
>   deprecated for some time, and was no longer built by default. The
>   documented instructions for converting video files to MPEG1 using
>   ffmpeg are outdated. I built the movie module was built and tested on
>   32-bit Linux Mint 17.1 (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr) and tested it
>   on a movie converted from MPEG4 using avconv (a fork of ffmpeg);
>   pygame segfaulted. Also note that pygame.movie was problematic under
>   Windows.
>
> The newer, experimental pygame._movie module, based on ffmpeg, never
>   worked for me on Linux; it would lock up. Also, libav is now preferred
>   over ffmpeg on Linux. Furthermore, it relies on SDL overlays, which
>   disappear in SDL2.
>
> As a side note, pygame.examples.movieplayer was re-purposed to use
>   pygame._movie instead of pygame.movie. This change was undocumented.
>
> I like the idea of movie support in Pygame. But pygame.movie uses the
>   outdated smpeg library, and pygame._movie never quite worked right.
>   Maybe another movie module can be written based on an existing command
>   line movie player program."

Comment: Now that was simple! I am getting a "NotImplementedError" now however -.-

Comment: `pygame.movie` was removed: see [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pygame-mirror-on-google-groups/c/5Ao4v0tw9sk?pli=1). If you want, you can use pygame 1.9.1 instead.